# How to update DynamoDB item using AWS Lambda and Axios

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, axios, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update a DynamoDB table item with Lambda and the below code works fine when the value is hardcoded.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: "us-east-1"});

    exports.handler = (event, callback) => {
        const params = {
            Key: {
                date: event.key1,
            },
            TableName: "todo-app",
            UpdateExpression:"SET task=:t",
            ExpressionAttributeValues:{":t":"This is my updated table"},
            ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
        };

        docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            }
        });
    };
```

However, this will always update the field with the hardcoded value of "This is my updated table".

**Is there a way I can simply replace the "This is my updated table" to `event.key2` like so:**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: "us-east-1"});

    exports.handler = (event, callback) => {
        const params = {
            Key: {
                date: event.key1,
            },
            TableName: "todo-app",
            UpdateExpression:"SET task=:t",
            ExpressionAttributeValues:{":t":event.key2},
            ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
        };

        docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            }
        });
    };
```

And here is the axios function just in case:

```
  async handleEdit(){
    let task = prompt("Enter texty");

    await axios.post(
      'https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/serverlessToDoFunctionUPDATE',
      { key1: 1591926275608 },
      { key2: task },
    );
  };
```

I know this might sound like a silly question to some of you but I can't seem to find a simple working example.

I'd appreciate any help with this. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to have neglected to mention that there's an API Gateway that is actually invoking the Lambda Function. This is crucial information. You need to add more information about how exactly the integration between API Gateway and Lambda has been configured.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise that it is relevant. The API Gateway is connected to this lambda function and it all works well with the axios API call. What information exactly is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I just realised what I was doing wrong. Maybe I made my question too complicated in the first place. I solved the problem by putting the event.key2 value in curly braces like so:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: "us-east-1"});

    exports.handler = (event, callback) => {
        const params = {
            Key: {
                date: event.key1,
            },
            TableName: "todo-app",
            UpdateExpression:"SET task=:t",
            ExpressionAttributeValues:{":t":`${event.key2}`},
            ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
        };

        docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            }
        });
    };
```

And formatted the axios API call correctly like so:

```
  async handleEdit(){
    let task = prompt("Enter texty");

    await axios.post(
      'https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/serverlessToDoFunctionUPDATE',
      { key1: 1591926275608, key2: task }
    );
  };
```